# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

My code as:-

```
function bindBranch(bankId) {
     $('#ddlbranch').unbind("change");
     $('#ddlbranch').get(0).options.length = 0
     $('#ddlbranch').get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select", "0");

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "InwardReportbranchwise.aspx/bindbranch",
         data: "{bankId:" + bankId + "}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (msg) {

             $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {
                 $('#ddlbranch').get(0).options[$('#ddlbranch').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.DisplayMember, item.ValueMember);
             });

             //if (type == "2")
             //    $(control).val(msg.d[0].branchesNationID).change();
             //else $(control).val(msg.d[0].BankId).change();

             $('#ddlbranch').bind("change", function () {
                 if ($(this).val() == "0") {
                     return;
                 }
                 bindControl($(this).val());
             });
             $('#ddlbranch').focus();

         },
         error: function () {
             alert('error');
         }
     })
 }
```

This is my code for binding bank with branch. I am getting an error on line no.2 as:-

> can not read property 'options' of undefined

Comment: I have another code same as above for different module. It is working but above code is giving error.

Comment: Does an element with id `ddlbranch` exist in the DOM at the time that code runs?

Comment: Yes.It is. i am having the same code for another module also but i am not getting exact problem

Comment: It's good to see `ddlbranch` html too

Comment: <td align="left" style="width:15%">
                                <select id="ddlbranch" style="width:140px" class="form-control" runat="server">
                                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

Comment: Your code looks right, and this error just happen when `ddlbranch` not ready in DOM, double check this. do you append this html part with javascript/jquery ? or ? / Also double check your code run after this html.